# MockServer | Return simple list in HttpResponse

Tags: java, unit-testing, resttemplate, mockserver

We're calling an external API that return a simple List, not DTO/Json, like `ResponseEntity<List<String>>`

In my tests I'm trying to mock the response using `mockServer` but failed to return the result as List (just String as it not helped me):

```
mockServer.when(restTemplate.getForObject(any(), any()))
            .respond(HttpResponse.response("{\"40\", \"50\"}")
                    .withStatusCode(200)
                    .withDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 1));

String user = "user";
String password = "password";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(user, password));
List<String> retList = restTemplate.getForObject(URI, List.class);
```

I tried with `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, none of them, double parenthesis but failed to return the response as List..

How can I do that correctly?

P.s. in the code all works well with the real API, response came as list as well. The issue is only in the tests, the error is:

> "Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found
> for response type [interface java.util.List] and content type
> [application/octet-stream]"

Comment: as far as I know, it is only possible if you have a wrapper for the List or use `String[]` instead of the List.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe this is helpful https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-json-list#3-resttemplate-with-user-list-and-parameterizedtypereference

Comment: The content-type is wrong; probably should be `application/json` instead.